# Substances with high physical expansive property/expansion after reaction

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I want to know if there is a substance/mixture of substances that expands more on some chemical or physical change, than what I've already seen.

Elephant toothpaste is a good example, a small amount of two substances expands into something with much more volume.

The list I have created so far is:

> 1. Diaper jelly
> 2. Orbeez
> 3. Elephant toothpaste
> 4. Water $\ce{->}$ Ice

A list of multiple substances with most expansive chemical or physical property will be appreciated.

The reason for my question: trying to develop a realistic 'smoke bomb' or some sort for a project photography. Best result would be lets say from small pellet, to huge smoke cloud.

Comment: Another example is the pharaoh serpent. But the question could be more defined.

Comment: Can you provide parameters for an acceptable final product? For example, I don't think you are including vaporization which increases volume much more than any of the reactions you've cited.

Comment: If you want large amounts of smoke, take a bunch of straw and sprinkle some water on it, and then burnt it. Although I am not sure how environmentally safe it is.